# CSS General Sibling Selector possible bug

Tags: html, css

I believe I might have run across a General Sibling Selector ~ bug but I'm not entirely certain.  My code `p ~ div` does not trigger the selector but swapping `p` with the specific class name `text_paragraph` does.  My fiddle and code are below.

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/t2Ljmgar/

```css
.outer_container {
  margin: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(216, 23, 27, 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.text_paragraph {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 2em/4em Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1.00);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(180, 180, 120, 1);
}
.text_container {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 1.5em/3em Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1.00);
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 251, 1);
}
p ~ div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_container">
  <p class="text_paragraph">Important header up top.</p>
  <div class="text_container">This is the first text on the page.</div>
  <div class="text_container">This is the second text on the page.</div>
  <div class="text_container">This is the third text on the page.</div>
</div>
```

Changing P to the specific class name triggers the selector.

```css
.outer_container {
  margin: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(216, 23, 27, 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.text_paragraph {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 2em/4em Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1.00);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(180, 180, 120, 1);
}
.text_container {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 1.5em/3em Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1.00);
  background-color: rgba(215, 215, 251, 1);
}
.text_paragraph ~ div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_container">
  <p class="text_paragraph">Important header up top.</p>
  <div class="text_container">This is the first text on the page.</div>
  <div class="text_container">This is the second text on the page.</div>
  <div class="text_container">This is the third text on the page.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's just CSS specificity. A class has higher specificity than a tag/element name. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: All of the tutorials I've seen online use tag names like P and DIV and they work fine.  I can't figure out why a tag name doesn't work in this specific instance.

Comment: Michael already told you why. Read about CSS specificity at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @DR01D it's the same reason this doesn't work. Has nothing to do with the sibling selector. It's simple CSS specificity. I recommend you continue to read up on CSS and learn this part, this is a fundamental aspect of how it works. https://jsfiddle.net/t2Ljmgar/1/

Comment: Sure enough you guys are correct, it's CSS specificity.  Hopefully this concept applies to more than `combinators`.  I'm going to spend some hours on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is overriding your generic element selector since it has higher specificity.

Comment your `.text_container` `background-color` property and see how the generic one takes over:

```css
.outer_container {
  margin: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(216, 23, 27, 1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.text_paragraph {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 2em/4em Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1.00);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-color: rgba(180, 180, 120, 1);
}
.text_container {
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 1.5em/3em Arial, Helvetica, "sans-serif";
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 1.00);
  /* background-color: rgba(215, 215, 251, 1); */
}
p ~ div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer_container">
  <p class="text_paragraph">Important header up top.</p>
  <div class="text_container">This is the first text on the page.</div>
  <div class="text_container">This is the second text on the page.</div>
  <div class="text_container">This is the third text on the page.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tested and you are correct.  So `P ~ DIV` can assign a background color but not OVERRIDE an existing background color.  But `text_paragraph ~ div` can OVERRIDE the existing background color.  My head is spinning.  8-)